# JavaScript listen on a port

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm using [dump1090](https://github.com/antirez/dump1090) to listen to and decode ADS-B signals. It outputs the data over port 8080 to a web front end and all is well. The code also produces output over ports 30003 and 30002 which are the raw messages. I'm trying to 'listen' for these messages however I'm getting a socket error. The code I'm using in js is:

```
function dumpSocket() {
    console.log("attempting to dump socket")
    let ws = new WebSocket ("ws://192.168.0.29:30003")
    ws.onmessage = function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> VM3157:164 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.29:30003/' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

If I netcat to the IP and Port however, I get the messages no problem. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use websockets to listen to raw tcp or udp socket, on the server side you need to create a websocket interface as well.

However in Chrome extensions you can make use of `chrome.sockets.tcp` see:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp

There is also some limited support by mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/TPC_Socket_API

Another solution is creating a nodeJS server, which will be listening on the raw tcp socket and converting it to a websocket.

you can also try websockify:
https://github.com/novnc/websockify

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. i think there may be packages in node.js which can help in that case. cheers.